# Abort a WCF RIA Call

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Is it Possible to abort or cancel a long running WCF RIA Invoke Operation ?
There is no database activity on the server side, so we dont have to rollback anything.

We are using Silverlight 4.0 on the client side.

Any pointers in the right direction is appreciated !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can call Cancel() on your invoke operation:

```
InvokeOperation<int> io = context.GetCount());
io.Cancel();
```

I believe this only cancels the operation on the client though, it doesn't stop anything on the server - something to keep in mind.